# Why is Ubuntu Music Streaming not available for Android, except for Google Play?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, music, ubuntu-for-android

Why is Ubuntu Music Streaming not available for Android, except for Google Play?

I was looking for it on F-Droid and it can't be found. Ironically, Ubuntu seems to suggest only Google Play - why doesn't Ubuntu support the open-source app store for Android?

Is there any officially recommended way to install the Ubuntu Music app for those of us that uninstalled Google Play, or are we supposed to find and compile the source?

Answer (score 1):

The `APK` is available on the [downloads page for the Launchpad project](https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-music/+download).